# How to get the last changed Revision per file

Tags: svn, deployment, build-process, versioning

for our build process i need to know the "last changed" Revision of each file in a certain repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn info` will output one line containing `Last Changed Rev:` which you could parse.

Comment: Also check out the --xml switch